# Can "taken" be used without an auxiliary verb? "When taken to this extreme..."

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, past-participles, auxiliary-verbs

Is it correct to use "taken" without an auxiliary (helping) verb? 
For example:

> In some cases, a more powerful racial group justifies the domination and, horribly, even the complete destruction of ethnic or racial minorities they consider to be inferior. When **taken** to this extreme, genocides such as the European Holocaust and the massacre in Sudan have threatened to wipe out entire peoples. [<sub>(source)</sub>](https://www.buenastareas.com/ensayos/Edd-Mi-Traduccion/6694114.html)

Comment: I think "when" should begin with a capital letter. "Taken" is not part of a passive or perfect construction, so no auxiliary verb is required. "Taken" is head of the non-finite clause "taken to the extreme", which functions as complement of "when".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the following, where the past-participle of the transitive verb **to truck** is used in a non-finite clause:

> Tomatoes can rot *when **trucked** long distances* , so they are picked unripe.
>
> *When **trucked** long distances* tomatoes can rot, so they are picked unripe.

The past participle of the transitive verb **to take** is used in your sentence 
in the same way. In the collocation "to take  {something} to an extreme", something which has degree, broadly construed, is brought (by an absent someone) to an extreme degree.

> The economic principle of free competition, when taken to an extreme, can result in great income disparities.

Comment: Because tomatoes cannot locomote.